# How to keep an Array in Jmeter parameters request field

Tags: arrays, post, jmeter

[image]

i need to add this array in the parameters in Jmeter inorder to complete the POST request. And i am getting a 400 error. 
This is the array, which needs to have a POST request:

```
conditions :[{accountStatus: 'UNVERIFIED'}, {accountStatus: 'INVITED'}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a Parameter with blank name and put your JSON array as a value like:

[image: Pass JSON Data]

You can use View Results Tree listener to inspect request and response details:

[image: View Results Tree]

Also make sure you add [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) to send at least `Content-Type` header with the value of `application/json`

Answer (score 0):

Add the JSON data in `Body Data` tab instead of parameters tab.

Comment: {"conditions": [{"accountStatus": "UNVERIFIED"}, {"accountStatus": "INVITED"}]}  I did this, but its giving a 400 error

Comment: That means you are able to send the request successfully. Check with the backend team/ API developer about the valid JSON data. Also make sure you are setting correct request headers like `Content-Type: application/json` etc.

Comment: Hi @vins, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution:

```
Add to the list of variables

Name - "someArray[0]"

Variable - "someText"
```

[See more about Request options here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N40WX.jpg)